# Is there a SqlAlchemy database agnostic FROM_UNIXTIME() function?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Currently I have a query similar to the below in flask sqlalchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

models = (
  Model.query
  .join(ModelTwo)
  .filter(Model.finish_time >= func.from_unixtime(ModelTwo.start_date))
  .all()
)
```

This works fine with MySQL which I am running in production, however when I run tests against the method using an in-memory SqlLite database it fails because `from_unixtime` is not a SqlLite function.

Aside from the running tests on the same database as production as closely as possible issue and the fact that I have two different ways of representing data in the database, is there a database agnostic method in SqlAlchemy for handling the conversion of dates to unix timestamps and vice-versa?

Comment: I think it's better to write your application to use a specific database instead of trying for a 'one size fits all' approach. That way you can take full advantage of the features of whatever db you choose, and not run into problems like this. And why would you use one database in production and a different one in testing anyways? Set up a test MySQL database to use...

Comment: I get the point as I mentioned it in my question but the ability to run the tests fast, in memory and as such offline among other things is a big benefit. I had assumed that sqlalchemy being a language agnostic abstraction tool would have a generic abstracted function that could be used for this or maybe SqlLite has no way to convert from unix timestamps to dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else interested in this, I found a way to create custom functions in SqlAlchemy based on the SQL dialect being used. As such the below achieves what I need:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles


class convert_timestamp_to_date(expression.FunctionElement):
    name = 'convert_timestamp_to_date'


@compiles(convert_timestamp_to_date)
def mysql_convert_timestamp_to_date(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    return 'from_unixtime({})'.format(compiler.process(element.clauses))


@compiles(convert_timestamp_to_date, 'sqlite')
def sqlite_convert_timestamp_to_date(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    return 'datetime({}, "unixepoch")'.format(compiler.process(element.clauses))
```

The query above can now be re-written as such:

```
models = (
  Model.query
  .join(ModelTwo)
  .filter(Model.finish_time >= convert_timestamp_to_date(ModelTwo.start_date))
  .all()
)
```